# jQuery Ajax forms plugin not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

Does anyone see the problem below? I'm trying to get ajaxSubmit() to work but the first baby step is failing. My understanding is that anything the action script - processaj.php here - outputs should be put into the #output element. I have processaj.php reduced to:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo ("In processaj.php");
?>
```

So I'm expecting "In processaj.php" to show up in the #output div when I submit something, but nothing appears.    Thanks for any help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax Form Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<style>
#output {
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: beige;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

</style>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({  
                    target: '#output'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form action="processaj.php" method="post" id="UploadForm">
        data: <input name="data" type="text" value="enter"/>
        <input type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using e.PreventDefault(), you should return false in the on submit callback function. As stated in the documentation.

```
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    // !!! Important !!! 
    // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Using return false, instead of e.preventDefault(), puts the processaj.php script on the browser, so I see "In processaj.php" but it's not on the original page that has the form, in the #output box. It looks like the ajaxSubmit is not doing what it should, i.e., keep the action page from downloading and just pipe any output of the action page to the #output div on the form page.

Comment: Strange. Do you get any errors in the developer console (chrome dev tools, firebug, ...)?

Comment: Yes! A check of the Firebug console showed an error that the jquery.forms.js file was not found, and that's because I hadn't uploaded it to the server!   With forms.js loaded my original code works, as does your version with the return false. Sorry!  Thanks for your help.